# Laptop will not wake from sleep with the lid closed with elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera

Tags: release-hera, suspend

I have the Power settings "for plugged in" with external monitor connected for it to "do nothing" when the lid is closed.  See the attached screenshot.  However, my laptop still goes to sleep and I can not wake it up without opening the lid.

[image: Screenshot of Power Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could be related to this bug: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-pantheon-shell/issues/219

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution.  If I go to the "Security & Privacy" settings and go to the Locking tab and set "Lock on suspend" and "Lock after screen turns off" both to OFF, I can wake my laptop back up without having to open the laptop lid.